# Google Drive File Downloading using PHP and api save on the server

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

the file from drive open in my browser but how can i download it on my server. 
I have tried but it's not working:

```
<?php
require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";

require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php";

require_once "google/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php";

require_once "google/vendor/autoload.php";

$DRIVE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'mobileformsafica@appspot.gserviceaccount.com';
$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = 'mobileformsafica-0497d13f3902.p12';

function buildService() {//function for first build up service
global $DRIVE_SCOPE, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH;

  $key = file_get_contents($SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH);
  $auth = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
      $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      array($DRIVE_SCOPE),
      $key);
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setUseObjects(true);
  $client->setAssertionCredentials($auth);
  return new Google_DriveService($client);
}
/**
 * Print a file's metadata.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param string $fileId ID of the file to print metadata for.
 */
function printFile($service, $fileId) {
  try {
    $file = $service->files->get($fileId);

    print "Title: " . $file->getTitle();
    print "Description: " . $file->getDescription();
    print "MIME type: " . $file->getMimeType();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
}

/**
 * Download a file's content.
 *
 * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
 * @param File $file Drive File instance.
 * @return String The file's content if successful, null otherwise.
 */

function downloadFile($service, $file) {
$downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
if ($downloadUrl) {
$request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
$httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {

return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
} else {
// An error occurred.
return null;
}
} else {
// The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
return null;
}
}
try {

//https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9ez4Vc-n0DbWkV6VmtRZFJIbnhqU3d2QmNHTTZfWWJYZGM0
$file_id='0B9ez4Vc-n0DbWkV6VmtRZFJIbnhqU3d2QmNHTTZfWWJYZGM0';

$service=buildService();
//printFile($service,$file_id);
$file = $service->files->get($file_id);
$content = downloadFile($service,$file);
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/filename","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file->getTitle()));
    header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($file));


print(downloadFile($service,$file));


  } catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred1: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

the script also eats a lot of incoming bandwidth. how to throttle or limit speed per task?

So i want something like a cache where i download file x once from google drive and after that the file should be served from my own server

full script [here](http://www.7logic.info/2017/05/google-drive-file-downloading-using-php.html)

Comment: What is not working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By the looks of your code you are downloading the file twice which would eat bandwidth.  Maybe only call downloadFile() once?   How exactly do you intend to serve these files?  Just put them in a directory under your web server?    Please format your code so that its readable.